# SQL Pro Convert DATETIME to DATE

Tags: mysql

I am exporting my old WordPress blog into a new Laravel build but having an issue. My publish date in my new system is just `DATE` but `post_date` in WP is `DATETIME` so I get an error. How can I export the data in the correct format?

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' CONVERT(post_date, DATE) as post_date
```

But get an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONVERT(post_date, date) as post_date' at line 1
```

I have also tried alter the old database to just `DATE` but it wont let me.

Error:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` CHANGE `post_date` `post_date` DATE
 NOT NULL

MySQL said: Invalid default value for 'post_date_gmt'
```

V. 5.7.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first SQL statement, the `CONVERT()` expression is misplaced ...

```
SELECT wp.*
  FROM wp_posts wp
 WHERE wp.post_type = 'post'
   AND wp.post_status = 'publish'
   CONVERT(wp.post_date, DATE) as post_date
```

The problem is that last line, MySQL doesn't know what to do with that. We could have just as well typed `slartibartfast` there, MySQL would be just as clueless what we meant.

Ditch the **`*`** in the SELECT list. We need to man up and write the expressions that the query is supposed to return. I don't have a definition of the `wp_posts` table, so I'm just making up column names here.  In place of `post_date`,  we can wrap that in a `DATE()` function, and assign an alias.  Like this:

```
SELECT wp.post_type
     , wp.post_status
     , DATE(wp.post_date) AS post_date    -- use DATE()
     , wp.author
     , wp.foo
  FROM wp_posts wp
 WHERE wp.post_type = 'post'
   AND wp.post_status = 'publish'
```

There are several other expressions that would work in place of the `DATE(post_date)`, We could do this:

```
     , DATE_FORMAT(wp.post_date,'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS post_date
```

or this:

```
     , CAST(wp.post_date AS DATE) AS post_date
```

or this:

```
     , CONVERT(wp.post_date,DATE) AS post_date
```

et al.

Comment: Perfect! The bottom solution is much easier to read as well. Still learning the basics of SQL Queries

Answer (score 0):

To convert timestamp to date:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`post_date`), '%e %b %Y') AS 'post_date'
```

Comment: Also, in your first query you have  `... AND post_status = 'publish' CONVERT(post_date, DATE) as post_date`. The way it is written, convert function looks like part of the select statement, not the where clause. If it is part of where clause then change to `AND post_date bla bla`

Comment: so I would change it to: `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`post_date`), '%e %b %Y') AS 'post_date' `? I get the same error

Comment: @Packy, if you're trying to simply convert date to timestamp then you would do:  `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date), '%e %b %Y') AS 'post_date'  FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'`. If you're trying to use a filter condition for post_date, then you would do: `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'` AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date), '%e %b %Y') between 'x' and 'y'`